# What's the easiest way I can sort the results of a list of events from a custom object?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, custom-object, lightning-apps, list

I have a custom object called event and it houses the events for a non-profit I am working for. I am trying to find a way to get the events to be sorted alphabetically when the page is pulled up. I am iterating over a list and grabbing each event to be displayed, so does there need to be some sort of recursive step in my code? Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

I am fairly new to Salesforce, so I apologize if this can be answered very easily, but I have yet to find anything online through my research.

Here's my event class:

```
public class eventClass {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Event__c> getEvents() {
return [Select Id, Name From Event__c];
}}
```

Here's my event component:

```
<aura:component controller="eventClass">
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.myAction}" value="{!this}" />
<aura:attribute name="events" type="Event[]" />

<ul>
    <h1>Choose an Event</h1>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.events}" var="event">
    <li class="minli"> <ui:outputText value="{!event.Name}" 
    class="eventName"></ui:outputText> <ui:button label="Select" 
    class="eventSelect" press="{!c.eventSelect}"></ui:button> </li>
    </aura:iteration>
</ul> 

</aura:component>
```

And lastly, my component controller:

```
({
myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getEvents");
action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
component.set("v.events", data.getReturnValue());
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort, simply change your return line to this:

`return [Select Id, Name From Event__c order by Name];`

That should return a sorted list to your Lightning component.

For more info on how to query from the database, you can look [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm?search_text=soql) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/).

Comment: You, sir, just showed exactly how new I am to this. Thank you so much!!

Comment: We were all new at one point. Glad to help! If this helped you, please upvote/mark as accepted so others can benefit too.